# localhost:8080 not running in unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, vagrant, unicorn

In my VM ubuntu32, I have nginx installed.

```
http://192.168.11.8/
```

displays Welcome nginx! page.

I added rails app in vagrant dir. I have unicorn gem installed and followings in railapp/config/unicorn.rb

```
working_directory File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
```

Now when I run

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant$ bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
```

, it displays the followings in my terminal.

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant$ bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
I, [2013-11-02T03:53:34.983828 #19364]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=9
I, [2013-11-02T03:53:34.984324 #19364]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2013-11-02T03:53:34.985178 #19364]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2013-11-02T03:53:34.986044 #19479]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=19479
I, [2013-11-02T03:53:34.986595 #19479]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-11-02T03:53:37.303696 #19479]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

However when I visit localhost:8080, it displays "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8080".

When I run `bundle exec rails s`, then the railsapp works at

```
http://192.168.11.8:3000/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running Chrome on the VM or on the host machine? `localhost` will only work within the VM—you'll need to use the IP of the VM otherwise.

Comment: Have you configured 8080 as a forwarded on your Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up nginx to listen on port 8080 and forward requests on that port to your app.  Check out the [example nginx config for unicorn](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/examples/nginx.conf) for how to set that up.

Hope this helps!